# hbase support concurrency if I fired query using phoenix then it will automatic check concurrency internally or not?

Tags: hadoop, concurrency, hbase, apache-phoenix, acid

I am using  phoenix query server for read write operation from `hbase` table. As `hbase` support ACID property so Do I need to manage externally transactions from phoenix server. As Transaction right now beta and I am not sure about it.

Comment: you might want to read more about Tephra the transactino framework.  We've had good luck with phoenix's tephra framework